# avoid returning @users inside a Link, with regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all @users contaning the symbol "@" in a string.

The conditions are:

1. Need not to be inside a link
2. Need to be after a empty space or not.

for example

```
@user1  follows other users @user2 and @user3
```

In this case I use the next regex and works very well

```
$regex = "/@+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/"; $str = preg_replace($regex...
```

When I add a Link (tik tok like with @ symbol included)...the regex above return as well "@dummy"

```
@user1  sent a link http://localhost/@dummy/video/7079513184146607365  to @user3
```

To fix this behaviour I add a "gap" before the "@" symbol in the regex

```
$regex2 = "/ @+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/"; $str = preg_replace($regex2...
```

It turns out it returns "@user3" but not "@user1".

I tried adding a gap before the "@" symbol.

```
$regex2 = "/ @+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/";
```

I need something like (adding "[^/") before "@" symbol to avoid returning all the @users inside a Link

```
$regex2 = "/[^/@+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/";
```

What regex can I use to return, in the last example "@user1", "@user3" but not "@dummy"?

Comment: Maybe just `$regex = '/(?<!\S)@+([\w-]+)/'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how could it be the javascript version? mine is "/ @[a-z0-9_-]+/gi;"

Answer (score 1):

With php you can update the pattern to get a match only and do not match http:// followed by optional non whitespace chars:

```
https?://\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|@\K[\w-]+
```

The pattern matches:

- `https?://\S+(*SKIP)(*F)` Match a link starting with http or https and then skip the match
- `|` Or
- `@\K` Match the `@` and forget what is matched so far
- `[\w-]+` Match 1+ times a word char or `-`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/BgO4JX/1).

Comment: thank you. this type of regex, depends of a php version?

Comment: @joe I don't know for which versions exactly it was introduced, but I am pretty sure that you can use it as it is pcre.